# how to set an empty initial value for react-date-picker?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-datepicker

I have a redux form which uses react-date-picker as it's date component, now on opening the form in edit mode, there in some cases the date field doesn't have a value or it has a blank (" ") value. Now in this case if my react-date-picker component doesn't find any suitable value to parse it shows "invalid date" on component, i tried with passing null, or by setting a check if there isn't any date or if it is blank pass undefined or null, i have googled it a lot but didn't find any suitable answer. My code looks like this

my custom date-picker component in my redux form :

```html
import { _dateField, } from '../../../containers/reduxFormFields/formFields';

<Row>
          <Col md={6}>
           <FormGroup>
            <ControlLabel bsClass="">Actual Start Date</ControlLabel>
            <div className="dateTimeSdiv">
             <Field name="actualStartDate" component={_dateField} className="form-control" formType="edit" defaultValue={moment(this.props.initialValues.actualStartDate)} />
            </div>
           </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col md={6}>
           <FormGroup>
            <ControlLabel bsClass="">Actual End Date</ControlLabel>
            <div className="dateTimeSdiv">
             <Field name="actualEndDate" component={_dateField} className="form-control" formType="edit" defaultValue={moment(this.props.initialValues.actualEndDate)} />
            </div>
           </FormGroup>
          </Col>
         </Row>
```

and my date-picker component looks like this:

```html
export const _dateField = ({ input, placeholder, defaultValue, className, formType,disabledValue, meta: { touched, error } }) => {console.log('values');console.log(defaultValue)
switch (formType) {
  case "edit":
   return (
    <div className="dateTimeSdiv">
     <DateField className={(touched && error) ? className + " error" : className} expandOnFocus={false} dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" updateOnDateClick forceValidDate defaultValue={defaultValue}  minDate={moment()} disabled = {disabledValue}>
      <DatePicker {...input} selected={input.value ? moment(input.value) : null} navigation locale="en" forceValidDate highlightWeekends highlightToday weekNumbers={false} weekStartDay={1} todayButton={false}></DatePicker>
     </DateField>
     {touched && error && <span> {error} </span>}
    </div>
   );
  case "create":
   return (
    <div className="dateTimeSdiv">
     <DateField className={(touched && error) ? className + " error" : className} expandOnFocus={false} dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" updateOnDateClick forceValidDate defaultValue={moment()}  minDate={moment()} disabled = {disabledValue}>
      <DatePicker {...input} selected={input.value ? moment(input.value) : null} navigation locale="en" forceValidDate highlightWeekends highlightToday weekNumbers={false} weekStartDay={1} todayButton={false}></DatePicker>
     </DateField>
     {touched && error && <span> {error} </span>}
    </div>
   );
 }
};
```

there are two seprate component which i am using for edit and create from each.
any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

When you're passing nullable date references around, you're going to want to make sure that you don't necessarily try to convert the value passed as a `moment` object all the time, unless you're absolutely sure the date value is going to be a valid date in a valid date format.

What I do for this is either write a helper class that attempts to parse the dates in a destination format and return the date in that format, or to return `""` if it cannot be parsed.

You can use the `moment(<value here>).isValid()` method to determine if the date you're passing is a valid date, and if not, return an empty string. I.e:

`moment(this.props.initialValues.actualStartDate).isValid() ? this.props.initialValues.actualStartDate : ""`

If you create helper method in your class, you can call that to place the value for the date so it always returns either the date or `""`.

Comment: hi mark thanks for the resolution will try to implement and get back to you soon.

Comment: Hi mark sorry for the late response, i tried with moment(this.props.initialValues.actualStartDate).isValid() ? this.props.initialValues.actualStartDate : "" but coudn't succeed getting the same "invalid date" on date input. i didn't use any helper class although just put the code from where i am calling this react-date-component in my UI.

Comment: Moment will not return a valid date if don’t give it a proper date format value. That’s the whole point I️ was trying to make with my answer, you need to validate the value you’re trying to give moment and adjust your data accordingly

Comment: yes mark i got it, but in my case i have to make the field look empty if the redux field doesn't have any value associated with it, still i didn't find any resolution of this, that if it is possible to show the react-date-picker field blank, i got you point that i have to pass a valid date format and date to the moment otherwise it will keep on returning the Invalid date on field. I tried to manage it by conditionally rendering an input field if there isn't any value and then replace that field with the date field if the user tries to enter any value(though onclick method of input field)

Comment: The value of “” should make the text box look empty, does it not?

Comment: sorry but i didn't get it. which text box you are referring here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158320/discussion-between-rajan-chauhan-and-mark-c).

Answer (score 0):

find some workaround here, just changed my code where i was passing my date (coming from DB) to react-date-component like this

```html
defaultValue = {moment(this.props.initialValues.actualStartDate)}
```

now changed code to

```html
 defaultValue = {this.props.initialValues.actualStartDate}
```

defaultValue property of react-date-picker was not taking the value as an moment object rather it worked when passed as string only.

Answer (score 0):

Using @material-ui/pickers, value={null} work but it will throw warnings in the console